# Is there any way to make an array of properties from an array of objects without iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry for the bad title - I don't know how to format it. I will explain my question .

So I have this req.user:

[image: click]

I want to build a middleware so I can check if the user has access to that region, by checking if any of the codes from req.user.privileges.region matches what I have in the DB (1 is for admins).

```js
middleware.access2 = function(req, res, next)
{
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        User.findOne({'username': req.user.username, "privileges.region": {$in: [1, req.body.regiune]}}, function(err, usr)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("middleWare.access2 - " + err);
            return res.redirect("/login");
        }
        else
        {
            if(usr !== null)
            {
                console.log(usr);
                return next();
            }
            else
            {
                return res.redirect("/login");
            }
        }
    })
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without iteration? I can build an array with the regions an user has (from req.user) and pass that to the query.

Can I access privileges.region in some way so I don't need iteration or should I use the idea above?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be a very simple `map()` but of course that does an internal loop

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I have never used map() and I don't know how I should do it. I would've done it with a for loop and .push()

Comment: If you wanted array of the region values ... `req.user.privileges.map(o=>o.region)//returns [10,2,15]`

Comment: Can I use that in the query? Like "privileges.region": {$in: [1, req.user.privileges.map(o=>o.region)]}

Comment: well map() returns an array so would need to use spread on it to do that

Comment: thanks for your time :)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "without iteration". Can you show what way you can see that does use iteration?

Comment: Like this: var x = [1];
        var y=req.user.privileges;
        for(var i=0;i<(req.user.privileges).length;i++)
        {
            x.push(req.user.privileges[i].region);
        }

Comment: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return an array of keys. Can be useful

Comment: @SanSolo I don't know if that will work because I have an array of objects (I mean, without iteration). I will try it out though. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @AndreiDaniel were any answers helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)
I have written a basic example, it can be refined.

```
const _=require('lodash')

const user={
  username:'marcu',
  privileges:[
    {
      id:1,
      region:10,
      write:1,
      edit:1
    },
    {
      id:2,
      region:15,
      write:1,
      edit:1
    },
    {
  id:3,
  region:20,
  write:1,
  edit:1
}
  ]
}

found=_.findKey(user.privileges,o=>o.region===15)

  console.log(found);
```

for `o.region===15`, output is 1, for `o.region===10`, output is 0,for `o.region===20`, output is 2 and so on.
findkey returns the index of the object that contains the value. When the value is not present, result is undefined

Comment: I don't know if that'll help me because the user changes, it's not the same everytime.

Comment: @AndreiDaniel this works for any user. I used this object only to illustrate that it works. In practice, the user would be fetched from MongoDB. It will work for any user fetched from the database

Comment: @AndreiDaniel please don't forget to mark this as answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with lodash

```
const _=require('lodash')

const user={
  username:'marcu',
  privileges:[
    {
      id:1,
      region:10,
      write:1,
      edit:1
    },
    {
      id:2,
      region:15,
      write:1,
      edit:1
    },
    {
      id:3,
      region:20,
      write:1,
      edit:1
    }
  ]
}

const userArr=_.values(user.privileges)

const found=userArr.find(o=>o.region==15)
console.log(JSON.stringify(found));
```

output:
`{"id":2,"region":15,"write":1,"edit":1}`

output will be undefined if value is not found